# If I make a layout for different API is it necessary to give ID in every API Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I make a layout for API 17 and API 21. I add here a TextView. and assign id in API 17, in API 21 I use TextView and add some more attributes that not supported in API 17.

../layout-v17/activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding"
  android:id="@+id/user_name"
  android:text="@string/user_name"/>
```

../layout-v21/activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding"
  android:id="@+id/user_name"
  android:text="@string/user_name"
  android:elevation="@dimen/elevation"/>
```

Is it necessary to use **ID** in both versions? and Why?

Comment: let just say you are at home and later at colz, so do i need to call you with some name to talk to you , i guess yes hence your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are referencing those IDs in your code then they are needed.
They can be removed if you are not using them .

Answer (score 0):

IDs are not needed if you don't need to access those elements programatically. But if you do, you can use the same ID, but make sure if you are programmatically manipulating the element and using any methods that are not available across all APIs that you check the version you are running on before calling those methods.